# Visual Studio 2010 - Code flow visualiser

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visualization, code-map

I would like to know if there is a tool which can help me in seeing which lines of code were executed within two break points.

Example: I have break points set at the beginning and end of a method. Now I want to see which  are the lines of code that got called from within this method. Basically, the tool must do a recursive deep debugging and record the file name and line number.

Answer (score 0):

[Runtime Flow](http://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) can show all function calls in a running .NET application, though it doesn't work with debugging - you need a separate application execution.

Comment: That is not a free software btw.